login.defs only for specified user
I need to set umask for specified user for all file he will make:
from terminal and from file manager ex Dolphin.
I have set umask in /etc/login.defs  but now ALL user have this umask.
There is a way to set logins.defs parameter for specified user?
Thanks in advance

If your system uses pam_umask, it should be possible to set per-user umask via their password entry's GECOS field - see somewhat related How do I use equal sign on chfn command?
